# Insert a space to separate a database

Tags: database, unix, awk, sed

Good morning, I have the following set, but with thousands of more information:

```
215 22221121110110110101 
212 22221121110110110101  
468 22221121110110110101
1200 22221121110110110101 
400 22221121110110110101 
100 22221121110110110101 
200 22221121110110110101
```

And I need to separate it into columns this way:

```
215 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 
212 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 
468 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1200 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
400 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
100 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
200 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

I tried to use a simple sed, but don't work

> sed -i -e 's// /g'

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using, and provide the names of the table and columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following with GNU `awk` and do let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '{num=split($2,a,"");printf $1;for(i=0;i<=num;i++){printf("%s%s",a[i],i==num?RS:FS)};}'  Input_file
```

Comment: Almost, the database looks this way:

`2152 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 

2122 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 

4682 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1

12002 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1

4002 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1

1002 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1

2002 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1`

Comment: @GregRov, so you mean it is not giving expected output, please clarify once.

Comment: Sorry, He is joining the value of the first and second columns. For example I have subject `215`, which has the following values `202121`. I need my output to be like this:
`215 2 0 2 1 2 1`, 
however, is going like this: `2152 0 2 1 2 1`

Comment: @GregRov, oh ok there was a typo I think, I corrected it from by changing `I=0` now, let me know how it goes now?

Comment: changing `i==num?"":FS` to `i==num?ORS:FS` will get rid of the last print new line.

Answer (score 5):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lane 'push @F, split //, pop @F; print "@F"'
```

- `-n` reads the input line by line
- `-l` removes newlines from input and adds them back to output
- `-a` splits each line on whitespace into the @F array
- [pop](http://p3rl.org/pop) removes the last element of an array and returns it, in this case it returns the second "word"
- [split](http://p3rl.org/split) turns a string into a list, with `//` it splits the string into individual characters
- [push](http://p3rl.org/push) is dual to `pop`, it adds the elements to the end of an array (in this case, it adds individual characters to the array currently containing only the first column)
- when printing an array in double quotes, by default the members are separated by spaces.

Comment: cool, this does the right thing by default!  doesn't add an extra space at the end.

Comment: good one, can also use `perl -lane 'print join " ",$F[0],split //,$F[1]'`

Answer (score 3):

you can use GNU awk [gensub](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function.

```
gawk '{$2=gensub(/./, "& ", "g", $2)}1' file
```

Answer (score 3):

to eliminate extra space at the end of line by other solutions you can use this

```
$ awk '{print $1 gensub(/./," &","g",$2)}'
```

Comment: gensub makes it gawk specific, can use `awk '{gsub(/./," &",$2); print $1 $2}'`

Answer (score 2):

Using `awk`'s [`gsub(regexp, replacement [, target])`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html)

```
awk '{gsub(/./," &",$2); print $1 $2}' infile
```

**Explanation:**

- `gsub(/./,"& ",$2)` match any char (except for line terminators) and replace it with the same, along with single space in second column of current record read.

> The Dot Matches (Almost) Any Character. In regular expressions, the
>   dot or period is one of the most commonly used metacharacters.
>   The
>   dot matches a single character, without caring what that character is.
>   The only exception are line break characters.

- If the special character `&` appears in replacement, it stands for the precise substring that was matched by `regexp`.

Test Results:

```
$ cat infile
215 22221121110110110101 
212 22221121110110110101  
468 22221121110110110101
1200 22221121110110110101 
400 22221121110110110101 
100 22221121110110110101 
200 22221121110110110101

$ awk '{gsub(/./," &",$2); print $1 $2}' infile
215 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
212 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
468 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1200 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 
400 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
100 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
200 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

speed comparison of some of the answers

```
$ perl -0777 -ne 'print $_ x 1000000' ip.txt > f1
$ du -h f1
169M    f1
```

time given for two consecutive runs

```
$ time perl -lane 'push @F, split //, pop @F; print "@F"' f1 > t1
real    0m34.004s
real    0m33.729s

$ time perl -lane 'print join " ",$F[0],split //,$F[1]' f1 > t2
real    0m23.291s
real    0m23.935s

$ time LC_ALL=C awk '{gsub(/./," &",$2); print $1 $2}' f1 > t3
real    0m30.834s
real    0m30.723s


$ diff -s t1 t2
Files t1 and t2 are identical
$ diff -s t1 t3
Files t1 and t3 are identical
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach with bash

```
while read a b;do
  printf "%s" $a
  while read -n1 c;do
    printf " %c" "$c"
  done<<<$b
  echo
done<lefile
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/ /\n/;h;s/\B/ /g;H;g;s/\n.*\n/ /' file
```

Replace the first space by a newline, copy the line, replace all non-word boundaries with a space, append the change line to the copy and then rearrange the line.

Answer (score 1):

How about `coreutils`:

```
paste -d ''                                \
  <(cut -d' ' -f1 infile                 ) \
  <(cut -d' ' -f2 infile | sed 's/./ &/g')
```

Output:

```
215 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
212 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
468 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
1200 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
400 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
100 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
200 2 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sed -i -e 's/\(.\)/\1 /g'
```

That is, capture character by character, then replace the capture with itself, plus a space.

Comment: I assumed they're plumbing via `awk`